# kubernetesでUnable to connect to the server が表示される

Tags: docker, windows-10, kubernetes

Windows10 proのマシンで参考書に沿って、docker desktopのkubernetesを利用しようとしたところ, `kubetcl cluster-info` のコマンドで下記のエラーが出てしまいました。

```
Unable to connect to the server: Service Unavailable
```

`kubectl config view` の実行結果は下記の通りでした。

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
  name: docker-desktop
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-desktop
    user: docker-desktop
  name: docker-desktop
- context:
    cluster: docker-desktop
    user: docker-desktop
  name: docker-for-desktop
current-context: docker-desktop
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: docker-desktop
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

ネットで検索して以下も試しましたが、解決には至りませんでした。

- dockerのイメージ、コンテナ、ボリュームを削除して容量を確保する
- Resouceを調整する

  - CPUs : 7
  - Memory : 18.50 GB
  - Swap : 4 GB
  - Disk image size 128GB(54.9 GB used)
- kubectl configでclusterのserverを指定

  - kubectl config set-cluster docker-desktop
    --server=https://[IPADDR]:[PORT]
- Docker Desktopの再起動

Windows10 proでdocker desktopを使用しております。

バージョンは下記のとおりです。

- docker desktop community : 2.2.0.5
- Docker Engine : 19.03.8
- Notary : 0.6.1
- Compose : 1.25.4
- Credential Helper :0.6.3
- Kubernetes : 1.15.5

この問題が解決したら、次の段階ではマニフェストファイルでnginxを動かそうと考えております。

自分ではもう解決策が見つからないのでお知恵を拝借したくここに書き込みました。
不足している情報などございましたら、ご返信ください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

kubernetes.docker.internal の名前解決はできていますでしょうか？
私も同様の状況でしたが、localhost:6443へのアクセスはできてため、
kubernetes.docker.internal を127.0.0.1に名前解決できるようにetc/hostsを変更しました。
さらに私の環境ではproxyがある環境でしたので、kubernetes.docker.internal がproxyを経由しないように、
no_proxyにkubernetes.docker.internalを追加して解決しました。